# How do I get C# to infer my generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
public class CatResult<T> where T : class
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public CatResult(T someProperty)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

I want to return this later on as a more general AnimalResult, it is identical although I will add extra properties in the future:

```
public class AnimalResult<T> where T : class
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Initially I did this:

`return new AnimalResult<KittyCat>(_someRepo.GetCatResult().SomeProperty);`

But I don't actually mind them being coupled. I was hoping to do something like this:

`return AnimalResult.FromCatResult(_someRepo.GetCatResult());`

However C# demands that I put the type parameter in, i.e. this:

`return AnimalResult<KittyCat>.FromCatResult(_someRepo.GetCatResult());`

I figured I could maybe create another class, called `AnimalResult` without any generic type parameters, and put `FromCatResult` on that, but that won't work because it needs to know T for the return type.

Is there a way to get it to automatically infer the type parameter?

Comment: Please, provide relevant *constructors'* code: your question is about *constructor* `return new AnimalResult<KittyCat>(...)` type inference

Comment: The return statement is used in lots of places to basically convert a `CatResult` to an `AnimalResult`

e.g. `public AnimalResult<KittyCat>> GetTheCat()`

Comment: If you want `AnimalResult.FromCatResult`, you need a non-generic `AnimalResult` class with a generic `FromCatResult` method. (Note that generic and non-generic classes can coexist with the same name.) Type inference on return values is impossible, but if the argument type can be inferred, it can be used in the return value.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's not possible to do `FromCatResult` without putting the type parameter in then, thanks.

Comment: `class AnimalResult { public static AnimalResult<T> FromCatResult<T>(CatResult<T> x) where T : class => ... }` will infer `T` based on the argument, without the need to specify it.

Comment: Ah I see, I was missing the `<T>` after the method name when I originally tried it, that's why it didn't work! Many thanks.